# Show that a set is open iff its complement is closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know that there are a lot of questions like this here on StackExchange, but they all use limit points.

My question says that if $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $U \subseteq X$ is open, then the set $U^c = X \backslash U$ is closed, and vice versa.

 A set $U \subseteq X$ is open if $\forall u \in U, \exists \epsilon \in (0, \infty) \ni B_\epsilon(u) \subseteq U$

 A set $Y \subseteq X$ is closed if $\exists (a_n) \in Y \ni (a_n) \rightarrow y \ni y \in Y$

 Plus I can't use limit points, just the definition of open and closed sets.

Comment: That definition of closed set cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: What do you mean, you can’t use limit points? Is it forbidden for you to define the concept and then use it? Is it forbidden for you to just use them without calling them “limit points”?

Comment: Your definition of closed sets seems to include limit points inside it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, yeah sorry I fixed it now.

Comment: What does that mean in plain English? Are you saying that, for each $y\in Y$, there is a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $Y$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=y$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes

Comment: "Plus I can't use limit points, just the definition of open and closed sets."  That's .... ridiculous.  The definition you give refers to "$\exists (a_n)\in Y\ni (a_n) \in Y \ni (a_n) \rightarrow y \ni y \in Y$.  That is the definition of limit point.  We cant use your definition of closed *without* using limit points.

Comment: Then that doesn't make sense, because then **every** set $Y$ will be a closed set: for each $y\in Y$, just take the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_n=y$.

Comment: "Are you saying that, for each y∈Y, there is a sequence (an)n∈N of elements of Y such that limn→∞an=y?" "Yes"  Then you are mistaken.  That is *not* the the definition of closed.  Where are you *getting* this problem from? What does *that* source have as definitions?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Here is the exact definition from the lesson: A subset G ⊆ X of a metric space (X, d) is called closed if, whenever (a_n) is a sequence in G and (a_n) converges, lim a_n ∈ G

Comment: *why* did you feel the need to obfuscate that with obscure and unconventional and ambiguous symbolic logic when you  have a perfectly clear and reasonable definition in English?  Note: That definition is quite different than what you wrote.  The definition says if a converging sequence exists, then any such sequence converges to a point in $Y$.  What you wrote was there exists one sequence that convergest to a point in $Y$ (a statement that is true of *all* non-empty sets)

Comment: And *that* definition makes sense, unlike what you wrote.

Comment: Note: a property of limit points $L$ is a limit point of $Y$ if there is a sequence $\{a_n\}\subset Y;a_k\ne L; a_n \to L$.  So this definition of yours is sayings, all limit points of $L$ are points of $L$.  So there is no point in saying you can't use limit points.

Comment: @fleablood Ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $U$ is open.    Let $(a_n)$ be any converging sequence of points where $a_n \not \in U$ (i.e. $a_n\in U^c$).  Suppose $a_n \to y$.

Your Task: Prove $y \not \in U$. (i.e. $y \in U^c$).

Then, by your definition, $U^c$ is closed.

(Hint:  For any $\epsilon > 0$.  As $a_n \to y$ there is a $N$ where $n > N\implies d(a_n,y) < \epsilon$.  So $n > N$ implies $a_n \in B_{\epsilon} y$.)

.......

Now suppose $U$ is a set and $U^c$ is closed.  Do a proof by contradiction.  Suppose $U$ is not open.  That means there is a point $a \in U$ where for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have $B_{\epsilon}(a)\not \subset U$.  That is to say there must be a $b\in B_{\epsilon}(a)$ where $b\not \in U$.

Your Task:  Create a $(b_n); b_n \in U^c; b_n \to a$.

This means that because $U^c$ is closed that $a\in U^c$ and that's a contradiction.

(Hint:  Consider $B_{\frac 1n}(a)$.  Pick a $b_n \in B_{\frac 1n}(a)$ where $b_n \not \in U$.  Prove that $b_n \to a$.)